# how to fetch fresh data on page load via redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my react native app, I have 3 main views, 
List view, which is an array of items. 
Details view, which shows the currently selected item.

[image]

Heres a sample code for how the List view is generated,

```
  return (
          <FlatList
            data={this.props.studentList}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <ListItem   onPress={()=>  this.handleonPress( navigate, item ) }
                roundAvatar
                title={`${item.agent_name} `}
                subtitle={`${item.address}, ${item.city}`}
                style={styles.row_alternate}
                containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
              />
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item._id}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
            ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
            ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
            onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
            onEndReachedThreshold={50}
          />
  );
}
```

Here using mapstate to props to genate the data:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {

  const properties = _.map(state.studentdata, (val, uid ) => {
      return { ...val, uid }; 
  });
    return { properties };
  };
```

Heres the redux call

```
import {
  STUDENT_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';

// inital state will have object  for list of properties
const INITIAL_STATE = { };

export default ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STUDENT_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      console.log(' - case STUDENT_DATA_FETCH_SUCCESS  = action =>  =');
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;

  }
}
```

But the issue is when I click an item on the List view, it passes the item to the Details view and it displays the item data that is passed to the Details view.

Redux Implementation:

import { STUDENT_UPDATE, STUDENT_CREATE, STUDENTS_SAVE_SUCCESS, SINGLE_STUDENT_FETCH_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  name : '',
  address : '',
  cell : '',
  _id : '',
  phone : '',
  comments : ''
 };

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action)  => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case STUDENT_FETCH_SUCCESS:  
      return action.payload;
      // return { ...state, state }
    case STUDENT_UPDATE:
      // console.log('21 - case PROPERTY_UPDATE  action =>  ', action);
      return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value }
    case STUDENT_CREATE:
        return INITIAL_STATE;

    case STUDENTS_SAVE_SUCCESS:
        return INITIAL_STATE

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

But my concern is I want the application to fetch the latest data from the database, so I want to transfer just the id of the item when user goes from List View to the Details View, on the page load it should fetch the fresh data using the id via the redux.

But my issue is I dont know how to use the redux to get me the new data.

I tried to implement single_student_fetch via redux but im not successful yet.

```
import {
  SINGLE_STUDENT_FETCH_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';

// inital state will have object  for list of properties
// const INITIAL_STATE = { };
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  agent_name : '',
  address : '',
  cell : '',
  _id : '',
  phone : '',
  comments : ''
 };

export default ( state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SINGLE_STUDENT_FETCH_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

I read online to implement with mapDispatchToProps, but I dont know how.

Comment: Try to condense your question. A lot of superfluous information. Hard to understand what exactly your problem is.

Comment: If you have to fetch your data from an external source, you will have to use a middleware like `redux-saga` or `redux-thunk` / es 2017's `async` `await`. Everything else in redux is a pure function.